# Where to download Facebook sdk for Visual Studio?

Tags: facebook, visual-studio, windows-phone

I'm trying to make a Windows Phone application with VisualStudio, This app has a button, when I click on that button, it post a sentence and image in facebook user. It's always the same so I will hardcode the sentence and the image.

To do that I think I need to download the Facebook sdk and add the Facebook.dll to my reference proyect, but I don't know where to download the sdk and how to add it.

Answer (score 0):

developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/
Sorry about that...

Try this FB SDK on codeplex which has some Phone samples along with the FB SDK.
http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Did you look to see exactly what SDK's are listed on that URL?

Comment: It's where I dloaded mine from, but I did put up the PHP link instead of the VS link, my appologies

Comment: There is no c# SDK on the developers.facebook url and the Facebook Toolkit on Codeplex has been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Facebook C# SDK, you can get the [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) from github or [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook).

The Facebook Toolkit SDK hosted on Codeplex has been abandoned.